# Why does SC.ScrollView bounce on touch instead of scroll?

Tags: sproutcore

On my mobile app, the SC.ScrollView appears to function properly in that it begins to scroll downward, however after I release my finger, instead of continuing to scroll down, it bounces back to it's original position.

It works perfectly when I run everything through `sc-server`, but once I push it to production using `sc-build`, it messes up.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, one of my stylesheets had done something stupid and manually set the height of the body to be `10,000px` which apparently messes up the scrollbars. They expect the body's dimensions to be exactly the same size as the screen.

I changed my css to the following and it works:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: SproutCore also applies those styles to the body element on its own; you may be able to save some bytes-over-the-wire by removing this CSS entirely.

Comment: That is true for SC pages, however, we have a lot of non-SC pages and I needed this to fix the height issues on them too :-)